# Webhook Telegram bot php don't run

Tags: php, https, webhooks, telegram-bot

I've started to create a bot telegram with webhooks.
My first question: I must put a url of web site with HTTPS? My site isn't a HTTPS but HTTP only. Telegram required only HTTPS?

Second question: When I enable a webhook I put this: "php://input".

```
php ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

$botToken ="*********************";

$website="https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;

$update=file_get_contents("php://input");//before: $website."/getupdates"

$updateArray=json_decode($update, TRUE);

$chatID=$updateArray["message"]["chat"]["id"]; $message=$updateArray["message"]["text"];

switch($message) {   case "/saluto":         sendMessage($chatID, "Ciao, sono il bot di Vincenzo e Francesco");         >break;      case "/comiato":       sendMessage($chatID, "Ciao è stato bello parlare con te");       break;      case default:      sendMessage($chatID, "Non ho capito!");          break; }

function sendMessage($chatID, $message) {       $url=GLOBALS[$website]./"sendMessagechat_id=".$chatID."&text=".urlencode($messag>e);    file_get_contents($url); }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, Telegram currently only supports HTTPS.

   > You need a valid SSL certificate for webhooks to work.
   >   https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#i-39m-having-problems-with-webhooks
2. You can grab the data you receive with `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`

   ```
   $data = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, true);
   $message = $data["message"];          // Message-Array 
   $chatID = $message["chat"]["id"];     // Chat ID
   $message_text = $message["text"];     // Message Text
   ```